# Meteor React: Accounts.changePassword is undefined

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, meteor-react

**Setup:**
I'm using Meteor 1.4.4.2 with React and the [`accounts-password` package](https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html) (versions `accounts-base@1.2.17`, `accounts-password@1.3.6`).

**Problem:**
When I import the `accounts-password` package (as instructed [here](https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-changePassword)) the function `Accounts.changePassword` is `undefined`. But other functions of the imported `Accounts` object are regularly defined, e.g. `Accounts.setUsername`.

**Question:** How to access the `Accounts.changePassword` function?

**Code Snippet:**

```
import {Meteor} from "meteor/meteor";
import {Accounts} from "meteor/accounts-base";

Meteor.methods({
  "changePassword"(oldPassword, newPassword, callback) {
    console.log(Accounts !== undefined); // => true
    console.log(Accounts.changePassword === undefined); // => true
    Accounts.changePassword(
      oldPassword, newPassword, callback
    ); // => Error
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check where you try to invoke the `changePassword` function. It is `client` only, see [here](https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-changePassword). So you cannot use it in a method. Use it somewhere under a `/client` folder and you should be good.

Comment: Thank you that was the solution!